# zf2 view helper across module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I created a helper in the application module, and it works perfectly. When I try to load it from another modules, such as user, it tells me that it can not find the class.

Class 'Application \ View \ Helper \ Footertable' not found

I tried to put this code in module.config.php well as the application module even in the same file of the user module.

```
'view_helpers' => array (
    'invokables' => array (
    'footertable' => 'Application\View\Helper\Footertable' 
    ) 
),
```

I think it's a problem autoloading class but I can not find information on how to load this helper when you are in another module

I invoke helper in view file using

```
$this->footertable()
```

work perfectly in application module but not in user module

any idea?

Hello,
but my code is correct

```
<?php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Footertable extends AbstractHelper{
    protected  $inizioFine;
    protected  $numero;

    public function __invoke($inizioFine,$numero){
        $this->inizioFine = $inizioFine;
        $this->numero = $numero;
        echo  sprintf('Mostra %d a %d di %d record',$this->inizioFine['start'],$this->inizioFine['end'],$this->numero);
    }
}
```

the space in config is an copy & past errors.
I still have the same problem: can't load helper from another module

update full error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\Footertable' not found in D:\www\httpdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170
```

path is

```
D:\www\httpdocs\test\module\Application\src\View\Helper\Footertable.php
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces on either side of the backslashes?

Comment: simple copy & past error

Comment: no one have solution?

Comment: The footertable invokable should only be in the Application module's module.config.php. If it still doesn't work, can you edit your question to include the full error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Tim, same error **Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\Footertable' not found in** i report error in question

Comment: Well, the problem doesn't appear to be in anything you've posted so far. What's the full path to the helper file (including the filename)?

Comment: ok tim I've updated the question with what you asked me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you posted doesn't look right. All the files in `src` for your Application module should be inside a folder called `Application`, since that's your top level namespace. So the path should be:

> D:\www\httpdocs\test\module\Application\src\Application\View\Helper\Footertable.php

That would explain why the helper can't be autoloaded, but I don't understand how it works in the application module if this is the case.

Comment: thanks it works. I have marked your answer as correct. i can't vote up :(

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems good. Probably the problem is in your helper class signature.

Since [PhpRenderer](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html) composes a [HelperPluginManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php) instance to manage helpers, your helper should implement the [HelperInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/HelperInterface.php) (1) to be registered correctly. Also you should write an `__invoke()` method within your helper to invoke it by method call. (2)

So, in your `Footertable` class, simply extend the `AbstractHelper` and make sure you have an `_invoke()` method. This is recommended way to write custom [view helpers in documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html).

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Footertable extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

And use it in your views like this:

```
echo $this->footertable();
```

It should work.

**Note:** You also have to register all helpers (and other classes) in your module configuration's invokables section without spaces between the backslashes:

**Wrong:**

```
'footertable' => 'Application \ View \ Helper \ Footertable'
```

**Correct:**

```
'footertable' => 'Application\View\Helper\Footertable'
```

Comment: this answer did not help me

Comment: ciro, you're trying to directly echo the output in your helper. this is not correct approach. simply return the output from helper and print it in your view.

Comment: i change in this way
 `return sprintf('Mostra %d a %d di %d record',$this->inizioFine['start'],$this->inizioFine['end'],$this->numero);`

but nothing changes
class not loaded